# exponential inequality $e^{-s(a+r)}<\sqrt{(1-rs)^2-s^2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Show there exists a $a>0$ such that
>   $$e^{-s(a+r)}<\sqrt{(1-rs)^2-s^2}$$ where $s=\frac{-1-r^2-2ar+\sqrt{(1-r)^2+4(a+r)^2}}{2(1-r^2)(a+r)}\geq0$ and $-1\leq r\leq1$.

This is a part of a bigger problem. I can solve it when $r=0$, in which case we have to prove:
$$e^{-2sa}<1-s^2$$ where $s=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4a^2}}{2a}$. We can choose $a$ small enough such that $0<sa<1.5$. Since $e^{-x}<1-x/2 $ for $0<x<1.5$, 
$$e^{-2sa}<1-sa < 1-s^2,$$
where the last step can easily be verified. Any idea for the general case?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: With the Substitution $$t=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$$ you will get
$$e^{-t}<1-\frac{1}{2}t$$.
I think that is easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have written my effort confusing. The last inequality is not what I need to prove. It is what I get but does not lead to what I need. Also, a little typo in your $t$, it has to be $t=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4a^2}}{2}$. If we substitute, we get $e^{-t}< 1-\frac{t^2}{a^2}$.

Comment: Lastly, my effort was on a simple case of the general case I want.